# sess.run() and ".eval()" in tensorflow programming

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science

In Tensorflow programming, can someone please tell what is the difference between ".eval()" and "sess.run()". What do each of them do and when to use them?

Comment: is it help full? https://github.com/Kulbear/tensorflow-for-deep-learning-research/issues/2

Comment: Yes, it was helpful. Thank you. So, if I have tensors, a &b, and f = a+b, I can do a.eval(), b.eval(), sess.run(f) and sess.run([a,b]). Is that write?

Answer (score 1):

A `session` object encapsulates the environment in which Tensor objects are evaluated.

If `x` is a `tf.Tensor` object, `tf.Tensor.eval` is shorthand for `tf.Session.run`, where `sess` is the current `tf.get_default_session`.

You can make session the default as below

```
x = tf.constant(5.0)
y = tf.constant(6.0)
z = x * y

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(z))   # 30.0
  print(z.eval())      # 30.0
```

The most important difference is you can use `sess.run` to fetch the values of many tensors in the same step as below

```
print(sess.run([x,y])) # [5.0, 6.0]
print(sess.run(z))     # 30.0
```

Where as `eval` fetch single tensor value at a time as below

```
print(x.eval()) # 5.0
print(z.eval()) # 3.0
```

TensorFlow computations define a computation graph that has no numerical value until evaluated as below

```
print(x) # Tensor("Const_1:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

In `Tensorflow 2.x (>= 2.0)`, You can use `tf.compat.v1.Session()` instead of `tf.session()`

Comment: @Pranav Kaushik, Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You