# How to print the tensorflow objects?

Tags: python, tensorflow

```py
def model_fn_builder(num_labels, learning_rate, num_train_steps,
                     num_warmup_steps):
  """Returns `model_fn` closure for TPUEstimator."""
  def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
    """The `model_fn` for TPUEstimator."""

    input_ids = features["input_ids"]
    input_mask = features["input_mask"]
    segment_ids = features["segment_ids"]
    label_ids = features["label_ids"]

    is_predicting = (mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT)         

    # TRAIN and EVAL
    if not is_predicting:
      (loss, predicted_labels, log_probs) = create_model(
        is_predicting, input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, label_ids, num_labels)



      train_op = bert.optimization.create_optimizer(
          loss, learning_rate, num_train_steps, num_warmup_steps, use_tpu=False)


  # Return the actual model function in the closure
  return model_fn
```

I want to print `label_ids`, `predicted_labels` and `log_probs` but I am not able achieve it using `tf.print`.

My model is having a very poor accuracy so i need to check it step by step. Hence I want to print the tensor objects step by step when I cal the function.
I am using `tf 1.15`.

Comment: To print the actual value of a Tensor object, you have to run code in a session. When you use a default session within tf.Session() block, then it evaluates the value passed in it. This method will give you the value of the Tensor. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61776624/13465258) answer.